# Ace Editor show & instead &amp

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using ace editor for read/write file content.

When I write text file with `&amp;`

example:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy &amp; of the printing and 
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard &amp; text ever since the 1500s,
```

and after save, I open saved file with Ace editor
and Ace show this:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy & of the printing and 
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
standard & text ever since the 1500s,
```

no more `&amp;` in content, only `&`

Ace is -aggressively- converting **&** character to **&amp ;** entity all the time, no matter what I try, no matter which selected "mode" is chosen (HTML,CSS,PHP, JS... you name it) and I don't want such behavior, I want loaded code to remain intact, on doc/file load/open and doc/file save/write

So I want to show **&amp ;** not **&** if code is written this.

**How to show exactly my code without ace cutting?**

This is my ace config on page:

```
<script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/batchfile");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/php");
    editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);


    /*editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: Infinity
});*/
editor.setOption("maxLines", 58);
    var input = $('input[name="update"]');

        editor.getSession().on("change", function () {
        input.val(editor.getSession().getValue());


    });
</script>
```

Comment: what code do you use to set value to the editor, sounds like you are not properly escaping html characters

Comment: This does not occur in Ace's kitchen sink, so your problem might lie somewhere else.